# How to center source code in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've been searching the internet for this but nothing relevant pops up ... so I ask you, is this possible to center text in VS ? (similar to distraction free mode in Sublime Text 2)

Comment: I think I was asking myself the same question for a while :) But I don't think that VS2012 has a distraction free mode :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the new features on the official website actually, and it seems like there is no mention about any "distraction free mode" : [VS2012 Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Full Screen mode? SHIFT+ALT+Enter activates this mode. You could also add the [Hide Main Menu extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813) from the Visual Studio Gallery and bump up the font size/zoom factor a little to make it even more "focused" on code editing. If using zoom for the font size [TroutZoom](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71870f0e-87bb-4a5f-8abd-e8e5e0ccb900) is also al really nice extension.